# GRUB BOOT ERROR ISSUE

Tags: boot, grub2

My computer has been working well until I woke up today to restart it then suddenly  it says

**GRUB booting, error loading**

I've tried to diagnose by live running Ubuntu and using boot error that scanned my boot issue and gave me this URL as a sort of log after scanning

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Twk88ZQm9d/

Anybody who might be knowing a workaround?

Comment: It's look as your HDD (/dev/sda) died.

Comment: Agree. No MBR, no partition table, a number of `Input/output error`s.